# I need a data logger that connects to Pager Duty and accepts push updates of simple data

Tags: logs

I have a simple script that periodically gets price data from the blockchain.

I need the script to push the data to a logger that Pager Duty can respond to.

The end goal is to get an alert when the price data strays from a norm. The end goal is summarized below

`my server--->data logger--->pager duty`

I am not bound by pager duty and open to other alert services. Other loggers I have come across want to monitor the health of my server/ app. All I'm interested in is pushing a specific data stream to a logger, and get alerts based on t he data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using prometheus on my server. This [tutorial](https://stackabuse.com/nodejs-application-monitoring-with-prometheus-and-grafana/) describes the set up